# Why when applying an integration or derivative operator on a polynomial, can each term of a polynomial be operated on separately?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I've never *why* that is, that if you have something like this:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^2-3x]$$

It can be written (and must in order to solve as far as I'm concerned) as:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^2-3x] = \frac{d}{dx}[x^2]\ - \frac{d}{dx}[3x]$$

Could someone explain the intuition behind this?

Comment: Derivative is a linear transform. Or prove that $(f+g)' = f' + g'. f = x^{2}, g = -3x$

Answer (score 2):

[Linearity of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_differentiation):  $$\dfrac{d}{dx} (a f(x) + b g(x)) = a \dfrac{d}{dx} f(x) + b \dfrac{d}{dx} g(x)$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the reference article. I hope "linear combinations" don't only concern linear functions but refer to any polynomial.

Comment: @sangstar Not only any polynomial, but also to *any* function. It may be exponential, logarithmic, trigonometric etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I said this with the stupid belief that something like $h(x)= e^x + 2e^{5x+3}$ was a polynomial because they were separated by $+$.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are [differentiation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules). The one you are interested is the sum rule.

Also the product rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^2-3x]=\frac{d}{dx}[x(x-3)]=(x-3)\frac{d}{dx}[x]+x\frac{d}{dx}[x-3]=$$
$$(x-3)\cdot 1+x\cdot 1=2x-3.$$